# Is nesting ARM Thumb2 "IT" instructions well defined?

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

If I have an ARM Thumb 2 instruction stream that looks like the following:

```
itt NZ
mov r1,r2
it MI
mov r3,r4
```

The IT block of the first IT instruction contains `mov` and a second `it`. Is this sequence allowable, or is it undefined behavior?

Comment: lack of research effort: [ARM's documentation seems clear](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjabicci.html) *The following instructions are not permitted in an IT block:* `IT` is the first entry.  This came up as my first google hit for `arm itt`.

Comment: A little understanding of the implementation; 4 control register bits gives you a strong hit that a global resource won't nest.  If the conditions are the same, you can just merge them.   Unfortunately, it looks like your are doing `if x > 0 return 1;  if x == 0 return 0 else return -1;` logic which is okay on ARM , but not Thumb2.  Just convert `itt nz` to `it nz` and you are fine with an extra op-code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An IT block must not contain another IT instruction. The result of your code is unpredictable.